# How can I get empid when I click command button

Tags: jsf

I have page that submit dates to database. When I click send button it is insert dates to DB, But I also want to insert empid to database depending on which account is logged for example, if it is just user then empid is 1 and if it is admin then empid is 2. I researched from internet and I couldn't find anything. How can I do this any suggestions for this?

In my emp DB I have

```
|empid |beginDate |EndDate|
        12/5/2014  12/5/2014
```

I got beginDate, enddate but I can not get empid when I click on submit button Sorry that my english is not good so it is difficult to explain my thoughts.

```
    @ManagedBean(name="vacationBean")
    @ViewScoped
    public class VacationBean implements Serializable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Date vEndDate;
private Integer userId;
private Date vStartDate;




Requestrelax vacation;
Employee employee;

@EJB
VacationLocal vacations;
EmployeesLocal employees;
@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    System.out.println("0");
    vacation=new Requestrelax();

}

public void addVac(){
    System.out.println("1");
    vacations.addEmployeeVacation(vacation);

    System.out.println(vStartDate);
    System.out.println(vEndDate);
}



public Requestrelax getVacation() {
    return vacation;
}

public void setVacation(Requestrelax vacation) {
    this.vacation = vacation;
}

public Date getvEndDate() {
    return vEndDate;
}

public void setvEndDate(Date vEndDate) {
    this.vEndDate = vEndDate;
}

public Date getvStartDate() {
    return vStartDate;
}

public void setvStartDate(Date vStartDate) {
    this.vStartDate = vStartDate;
}

   }
```

In xhtml of header section I got username #loginBean.userName}

```
<p:dataTable styleClass="vtable" editable="true" var="user"
editMode="cell" value="#{userBean.employeeList}">

<p:column styleClass="columntd"
    headerText="#{text['user.startedDate']}">

    <p:calendar widgetVar="fromCal"
        value="#{vacationBean.vacation.beginDate}">
        <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{dayDiffBean.fromSelected}"
            update="diff" />
    </p:calendar>
</p:column>
<p:column styleClass="columntd"
    headerText="#{text['user.finishedDate']}">

    <p:calendar widgetVar="toCal" value="#{vacationBean.vacation.endDate}">
        <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{dayDiffBean.toSelected}"
            update="diff" />
    </p:calendar>

</p:column>

<h:commandButton styleClass="sndbutton1"
    value="#{text['employee.send']}" action="#{vacationBean.addVac}" />
```

In loggin bean I used this
 [LoginBean](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/93c832e80936afa97e1b)

So when I click coomandbutton I want to insert userId=e.getEmployeePkId(); to database depending on which user is logged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get property values from another ManagedBean, you can use the `@ManagedProperty` to inject them to your property.

An example based on your scenario would be

`@ManagedProperty(value = "#{loginBean.userId}")
private integer userId;`

And from there, you can insert `userId` into your database.

Comment: Alvin Sim can you this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24399208/how-can-i-use-multiple-value-jsf ???

Comment: can i write jwithout = like value"{loginbean.userid}

Comment: @user3724426 I doubt you can write it without the `value` http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedProperty.html